# Delete message by ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I've created a bot that shows a vote panel for polls on my server, ideally I would like it to delete the old message and send a new one to update the poll when people vote on things.

I've managed to get the old message ID using message.channel.fetchMessage and 'LastMessageID' is the right ID, but I can't seem to find a way to select and delete the message without making a load of errors in my console.
For example I've tried:

```js
message.channel.fetchMessage(LastMessageID)
 .then(message.delete)
```

And it just gives the following errors:

```
(node:82184) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined
    at resolve (C:\Users\Username\Desktop\TestBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Message.js:480:14)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at delete (C:\Users\Username\Desktop\TestBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Message.js:479:14)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7) (node:82184) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2) (node:82184) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I feel really silly that I can't figure out how to do something so simple as delete a message by its ID. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: the error it self is about rejection. If you do `x.then().catch(er => console.error(er))` then the current error would disappear. However this wouldn't fix the deletion. Can we see your `message.delete` function?

Comment: That pretty much is the entire function. @EduardJacko

    // Delete the old message.
    if (LastMessageID != "") {
     message.channel.fetchMessage(LastMessageID)
      .then(message.delete())
      .catch(er => console.error(er))
    }

I'm just trying to fetch the message with that ID and delete it.
I know the LastMessageID is correct because I can manually copy the ID from Discord to check. (LastMessageID is just bot.user.lastMessage.id)

Sorry if this isn't what you meant, I'm very new to JS.

Comment: @EduardJacko Alternatively, here's the code on hastebin seeing as I apparently can't figure out how comment formatting works. [link](https://hastebin.com/ohukiqotiz.js)

Comment: Well, you said you are new in JS, then maybe try `.then( message => message.delete())` very common mistake by novice.

Comment: also I know your ID is not the issue because the error complain about unhandled promise rejection which comes from https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/16076124b2687ebb9cde40ec8585fca4c6588869/src/structures/Message.js#L485. Basically `this` is undefined which mean you scope is bind somewhere else. Above suggestion should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the thing you're looking for: finds the message and then deletes it.

```js
// ASSUMPTIONS:
// channel: the channel you want the message to be sent in
// lastmsg: the id of the last poll message

channel.fetchMessage(lastmsg).then(msg => msg.delete());
```

This is fine, but let me suggest you a better way to do it:

```js
// Option A: delete the old message and send the new one in the same function
channel.fetchMessage(lastmsg).then(async msg => {
  await channel.send("Your new message.");
  if (msg) msg.delete();
});

// Option B: if you have a poll dedicated channel that is kept cleaned and organized, 
// you can edit the old message (you avoid notifications for every update)
channel.fetchMessage(lastmsg).then(msg => {
  if (msg) msg.edit("Your new message.");
});
```